# How to use awk to print a line before match and until next blank space after the match

Tags: bash, awk, scripting

For example, I have a variable `$var`

```
 awk  '/'$var'/ {  }' file.txt
```

Once awk matches the variable in text file, I wanna to start printing one line before the match until next blank space.

Edit:
My File

```
AAAA
BBBB
SSSS
CCCC
DDDD
LLLL
PPPP
ASAD
BEKK

SSEE
AASS
```

if `$var = SSSS`, my ouput should look like:

```
BBBB
SSSS
CCCC
DDDD
LLLL
PPPP
ASAD
BEKK
```

Sorry I am new here If my explanation is not very clear

Comment: please add some sample input lines and exact output required for that (including value in `$var`)

Comment: You should include a second `SSSS` line inside the block you want to print so we can see how you want that handled. Can your target string `SSSS` contain regexp metachars like `.` or `*`? If so do you want them treated as metachars or as literal? What if you have multiple such blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your shown samples and attempts, please try following GNU `grep` solution. Written and tested in GNU `grep`:

```
grep -ozP '(?:[^\n]+\n)?AAAA(?:\n[^\n]+)*'  Input_file
```

---

---

***Few scenarios*** Checking above code with shown samples and with 3 different input strings.

***1st scenario:*** Checking with input string `SSSS`:

```
grep -ozP '(?:[^\n]+\n)?SSSS(?:\n[^\n]+)*' Input_file
BBBB
SSSS
CCCC
DDDD
LLLL
PPPP
ASAD
BEKK
```

***2nd scenario:*** Checking with string `AAAA` in code:

```
grep -ozP '(?:[^\n]+\n)?AAAA(?:\n[^\n]+)*' Input_file
AAAA
BBBB
SSSS
CCCC
DDDD
LLLL
PPPP
ASAD
BEKK
```

***3rd scenario:*** Checking with input string `BEKK`:

```
grep -ozP '(?:[^\n]+\n)?BEKK(?:\n[^\n]+)*' Input_file
ASAD
BEKK
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -v tgt="$var" '!f && ($0==tgt){print prev; f=1} f{if (NF) print; else exit} {prev=$0}' file
```

The above assumes you just want the first such range printed. If that's wrong then change to:

```
awk -v tgt="$var" '!f && ($0==tgt){print prev; f=1} f{if (NF) print; else f=0} {prev=$0}' file
```

Both scripts assume you want to do a full-line string match.

Comment: How should I change it if I want to say that match `*AAAA*` not a full line ?

Comment: Do you want a string match or a regexp match?

Answer (score 1):

You may use this `awk` solution using `match` function and empty `RS`:

```bash
awk -v var='SSSS' -v RS= 'match($0, "(^|[^\n]+\n[^\n]*)" var) {print substr($0, RSTART)}' file
BBBB
SSSS
CCCC
DDDD
LLLL
PPPP
ASAD
BEKK

# more testing
awk -v var='BEKK' -v RS= 'match($0, "(^|[^\n]+\n[^\n]*)" var) {print substr($0, RSTART)}' file
ASAD
BEKK

awk -v var='AAAA' -v RS= 'match($0, "(^|[^\n]+\n[^\n]*)" var) {print substr($0, RSTART)}' file
AAAA
BBBB
SSSS
CCCC
DDDD
LLLL
PPPP
ASAD
BEKK
```

Comment: This works in this file but how should I change it to much `*AAAA*` it can start and end with anything like XXX_CCFA-AAAA-ZZZ_PROD ?

Comment: I have modified the answer for your extended requirement. It is always better to provide clear requirements in question at first place.